# How to return rows in one table whose field contains a string from any row in another table?

Tags: mysql, join, full-text-search, match

I have the following table structure in MySQL 5.6:

```
CREATE TABLE `dictionary` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `word` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `word` (`word`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `sentences` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sentence` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `sentencefulltext` (`sentence`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to return all the sentences that contain any of the words in my dictionary. I don't really care about word boundaries, it can be a basic substring.

Fulltext MATCH AGAINST seems to only work with strings and not a select from another table. As for LIKE and REGEXP, they seem to take for ages since I have about 500k rows of sentences and 50k rows of words in my dictionary.

One option would be to go through the dictionary row by row in a program and call a select on each row, but I'd rather do it in a single SQL statement.

If someone has any ideas, please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try something like this -

```
 SELECT *
      FROM `sentences`,'dictionary'
     WHERE INSTR(word,''+sentence+'') > 0
```

when you use like with % sign - there is no indexing that is why it is too slow so you may need full text search:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: The fields seem to be in the wrong order there. I got it to work just a bit faster than LIKE with a small subset of the data with the following SQL:
`SELECT * FROM \`sentences\`,\`dictionary\`
WHERE INSTR(sentence,word) > 0;` However this takes for ages with the big dataset.

Comment: Does anyone have any more ideas?

Comment: check my edit above and like and instr are always going to be slow - may be think of redesigning the table so you dont have to perform a like. I haven't tried 'IN' but i think it will be slow too

Comment: I started of with full text searching, but could not reference the dictionary table in the match against clause, but instead could only use text strings. It would be perfect if I could do it like this: 
`SELECT *
      FROM \`sentences\`,\`dictionary\`
     WHERE MATCH \`sentence\` AGAINST(\`word\`);`